# GetStream: How to allow fellow team members access to app secret settings etc

Tags: getstream-io

I have created an app inside getstream.io. I then added a team member but she does not seem able to see the app I created.

How do I ensure that team members can see the app and their secret key are viewable by fellow team members inside getstream.io?

Answer (score 0):

Has the team member accepted the invitation (sent in an email)?